# Dynamically assign a sobject field name

Tags: apex

Can i dynamically assign a sobject field a value.?
Due to the poor data model setup of existing I am forced to do this

My issue is fieldname on object is stored at some other object.Say for eg i have a string fieldname where i store actualfieldname  of the object.Now i want to update this field of the object as below

```
string fieldname = 'Name'
test__C c = new test__C();
c.fieldname = 'Hello';
```

This throws me an error.Is there any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, that is possible (see also the [documentation for all sObject methods](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_Left.htm#CSHID=apex_methods_system_sobject.htm%7CStartTopic=Content%2Fapex_methods_system_sobject.htm%7CSkinName=webhelp)):

Use `c.put(fieldname,'Hello')`

Comment: You can also use `c.get(fieldname);` to get the value from the SObject dynamically. See [here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm) for more info